# Most performant TSQL loop for emailing?

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2012, database-performance

I have two tables: 1) order is 1:N with 2) order_item. I need to send 1 email to each customer email address that is on the order table where conditions match on order_item. The email will contain a list of order_items that match those conditions

Is this the most performant way to do this in T-SQL 2012?

```
DECLARE @email NVARCHAR(254);

DECLARE email_cursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT o.email
    FROM order_item AS i
        INNER JOIN order AS o ON i.order_id = o.order_id
    WHERE i.send_email = '1';

OPEN email_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM email_cursor INTO @email;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'mail'
        @recipients = @email,
        @subject = 'Order Items',
        @body = 
        N'<table>' +
            N'<tr>' +
                N'<th>Order</th>' +
                N'<th>Item</th>' +
            N'</tr>' +
            CAST (( 
                SELECT 
                     i.order_id,
                     i.name
                FROM order_item AS i
                    INNER JOIN order AS o ON i.order_id = o.order_id
                WHERE i.send_email = '1'
                  AND o.email = @email
                FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
            ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
        N'</table>',
        @body_format = 'HTML';
END;
```

**UPDATE** From @JamieD77's suggestion to use table variable:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(
    email NVARCHAR(254),
    order_id INT,
    name NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT 
    o.email
    i.order_id,
    i.name
FROM order_item AS i
    INNER JOIN order AS o ON i.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE i.send_email = '1'.

DECLARE @email NVARCHAR(254);

DECLARE email_cursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT email
    FROM @temp

OPEN email_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM email_cursor INTO @email;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'mail'
        @recipients = @email,
        @subject = 'Order Items',
        @body = 
        N'<table>' +
            N'<tr>' +
                N'<th>Order</th>' +
                N'<th>Item</th>' +
            N'</tr>' +
            CAST (( 
                SELECT 
                     order_id,
                     name
                FROM @temp
                WHERE email = @email
                FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
            ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
        N'</table>',
        @body_format = 'HTML';
END;
```

**UPDATE 2** I think using a fast_forward cursor is faster?

Comment: I would say yes... since it's very likely that each order will have a distinct number. And sp_send_dbmail does not support sending a batch of e-mails in "bulk", only a single e-mail to multiple recipients.

Comment: Even though it does not look pretty, and SQL Server likes SET operations better, this would be one of the good ways to do this. However, I would still advise you to check the Estimated Execution plan, and do a comparison between an actual looping vs using Cursor.

Comment: I would say, did you try how well it behave? How much time take to run? But yes also looks good. Just make sure you have index for order and order_item

Comment: why not make your `order_item INNER JOIN order` query a temp table or table variable once and use that in your Cursor and sp_send_dbmail function instead of hitting the database multiple times

Comment: @JamieD77 You are totally right!

Answer (score 0):

Try deriving the xml/html in the table variable rather than in the cursor.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(
    email NVARCHAR(254),
    order NVARCHAR (MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (email, order)
SELECT 
    o.email,
    c.order
FROM order AS o
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CAST (( 
            SELECT 
                 oi.order_id AS td,
                 oi.name AS td
            FROM order_item oi
            WHERE oi.order_id = o.order_id
            FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
        ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) )
) c (order)
WHERE i.send_email = 1

DECLARE @email NVARCHAR(254),

DECLARE email_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT email, order
FROM @temp

 OPEN email_cursor;
 FETCH NEXT FROM email_cursor INTO @email, @order

WHILE ( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'mail'
        @recipients = @email,
        @subject = 'Order Items',
        @body = 
            N'<table>' +
            N'<tr>' +
            N'<th>Order</th>' +
            N'<th>Item</th>' +
            N'</tr>' +
            @order +
            N'</table>',
    @body_format = 'HTML';

    FETCH NEXT FROM email_cursor INTO @email, @order
END;

CLOSE email_cursor
DEALLOCATE email_cursor
```